# Facebook 191 redirect_uri error only in facebooktab

Tags: php, facebook, api, tabs

I have been searching this site for 3 days now and I still can't fix my problem.

My problem is that I get the populair 191 error on FaceBook.

I know there are a lot posts about it, but I still can't fix it and that's why I make my own post.

My situation:

When I call my page directly from my server the share option works, but when I call the exact same page from my tab on FaceBook it doesn't work and I get the 191 error.

This is my code:

```
     <script src='https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>

<script>

      FB.init({appId: "182845311856304", status: true, cookie: true});

      function postToFeed() {

        // calling the API ...
        var obj = {
          method: 'feed',
          redirect_uri: 'http://www.permobil.socialdutch.nl/socialdutch/resporter/app/likefb.php',
          link: 'https://www.facebook.com/amateurvoetbal/app_182845311856304',
          name: 'Resporter',
          picture: '',
          caption: '',
          description: ''

        };



        FB.ui(obj);
      }

</script>
```

My developers details are:

(Can't post images, because I just registered.)

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/443/naamloosh.jpg/

Would appreciate some help!

Comment: Your redirect_uri points outside of facebook.com … try not setting this value at all, and have the SDK fill it in automatically.

Comment: So I need to leave it blank? like ''?

Comment: Try removing the parameter completely from your API call.

Comment: Tried to leave it blank with only quotes and still get the same error.

Comment: Will try that now, hold on..

Comment: Tried to remove the parameter, but still getting same error

Comment: Why is your Page Tab URL missing the _permobil_ subdomain part? That could be the problem.

Comment: That's because I have 2 different maps for public_html and private_html

Comment: And why are the HTTP and HTTPS version the same for your Canvas URLs then?

Comment: I fixed it, the solution was the app domain. I had to fill all my domains in it. I will post a screenshot

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/834/naamloosak.png/

Comment: Thank you for your help! Appreciate it!